# paper-sliders from Polymer I want to change the axes for draging

Tags: css, angularjs, polymer

I have the following problem:
  I`m using with angular 2 the polymer library, more precise paper-slider.
  I had to put my slider from css from horizontal position to vertical. The problem is that now if I keep a click on the slider and I move the mouse left-right the slider moves up-down, how can I change the axes of the slider in order to use my slider in vertical position.

Kind Regards,
A developer in need :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use the s-slider element, there you can set vertical property
https://github.com/StartPolymer/s-slider